# Group by Clause in SQL Server 2012 Altering Column Mapping

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, group-by

I have written a query to extract only one record based on two columns distinct value, after hours of searching (my SQL is horrible) I came up with this query which seems to return unique records. but , But it is altering the mapping of columns i.e. on column's value is returned with others

```
select   
    Start_Object_ID, 
    MIN(OperationID) as OperationID, CallScope,
    MAX(ActualCall) as ActualCall, 
    MAX(End_Object_Name) as End_Object_Name, 
    MAX(End_Object_ID) as End_Object_ID  
FROM 
    t_Delegations 
WHERE 
    CallScope != '' 
    AND Start_object_ID = 21  
GROUP BY 
    Start_object_ID, callScope
```

Here is the result that have altered mapping with the columns.

[Altered Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Okrrr.jpg)

And here are all the records belonging to object 21 and operation 17
With simple query

```
SELECT * 
FROM t_delegations 
WHERE Start_object_ID  = 21 
ORDER BY Start_object_ID, OperationID`
```

[Original Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMgcI.jpg)

While all I wanted was to select only one row (All columns) Where two columns `Start_Object_ID` And `CallScope` is Same e.g.  Two records with `Start_Object_ID =21 and CallScope = 'emf'` but with a different/or Similer 'Actual Call' ,  only need one of it.

Comment: If the actual call is the same you don't want it and if they are different/similar you don't care which row you select?

Comment: Where Start_object_ID and Call scope are same ,  Select one row
e.g 1-Start_object_ID =  21   and Call Scope = emf   , 2- Start_object_ID =  21   and  Call Scope = emf  , Select only one  but if 
3-Start_object_ID =  22   and Call Scope = emf  then select it as well.

Comment: And for Actual Call column i don't care, if it is similar or different , though i care about the original mapping . and if two similar rows are found i don't care which one is select , i only need one , it can be any one of them .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use GROUP BY, it is getting the field individually:
Example

### Col1 | Val1 | Val2

a  |   1  |  2

a  |   2  |  1

If you run a query

```
SELECT
    Col1
    , MAX(Val1) AS Val1
    , MAX(val2) AS Val2
FROM
    <<Table>>
GROUP BY
    Col1
```

You will get

a    |    2   |   2

Because it compare columns individually, and take the max of it.

---

The query below will do what you want.

```
WITH cte AS (
SELECT
    Start_Object_ID, 
    CallScope,
    OperationID, 
    ActualCall, 
    End_Object_Name, 
    End_Object_ID 
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Start_Object_ID, CallScope ORDER BY Start_Object_ID ) AS RowNum
FROM t_delegations 
)
SELECT 
    Start_Object_ID, 
    CallScope,
    OperationID, 
    ActualCall, 
    End_Object_Name, 
    End_Object_ID 
FROM
    cte
Where
    RowNum = 1;
```

Comment: Thank a lot this query is doing exactly what was required , though , i would like to know why my query  was altering the mapping between columns  ?

Comment: @CommonMan I added the explanation.

Comment: Thanks again, I was hitting my head for four hours , to understand that .